# Is there any way to display HBITMAPS for debugging purposes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I work with a native c++ win32 app and often times I hope there was a way to, while debugging my application if I can visually see what a HBITMAP contains (all GDI objects would be nice, like HDCs, Fonts, etc).

So the question, is there any tool out there that I can't find with google that display those objects in a visual way while debugging?

Comment: `HBITMAP`, just like `HDC`, `HFONT`, `HWND` and other Windows handles, are opaque types. There's nothing to "see", because they mean nothing outside the Win32 API code itself, and that code is not published. Consider them as a "black box" concept, where what goes on internally is not available; you only get access to the public (external) parts.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. There could potentially be a visual studio extension that took the handle and used it to draw it somewhere to display for debugging. It doesn't need to know what's inside. Just use the same public API to draw it.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eae1b934-bff2-4a20-99ef-41e6b9a4aee4, http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0954c361-ae31-491b-a503-926032c79a3d

Comment: What I mean by that is what I clearly said. *There is nothing to display that would be meaningful without access to the internal source code of Windows itself.* There is no Visual Studio extension that has access to something that is not available to people that don't have access to the Windows source code. (If I give you the number `12345` and tell you that's my secret code, it won't do you any good unless you know what that code is attached to in order to use it. MS doesn't document the internals of various handle types.)

Comment: Still, don't know how that makes writing a visual studio extension impossible, it'll just need to take the number 12345 and Bitblt it to a debugger window, I don't know why access to Windows internal representation is required.

Comment: @KenWhite I think the asker wants a debugging tool that will display an arbitrary HBITMAP on the screen. I don't know of such a tool, but writing a quick window on the side to do it should suffice... or see Jerry Coffin's links above.

Comment: @andlabs: No, the poster is asking for something that will display the underlying contents of a generic Windows handle (such as HBITMAP, HDC, or other handle), and there is no such tool. A quick examination of Windows.h will show you that `HBITMAP` and `HDC` and `HWND` all ultimately start from the same generic numeric type at the root, and therefore they're all basically the same type. It's the assignment of the value to the variable that is meaningful, but only inside the Windows libraries themselves. It's like a generic pointer, in essence; you can't necessarily tell to what it points.

Comment: Ah, all right then... Also, rereading the question, he seems to think an HBITMAP contains a HDC and fonts, which I strongly doubt they do... (Also things get more fun with STRICT defined ;) )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *"visually see what a HBITMAP contains"*. Are you looking for a way to have the bitmap object rendered to screen, or are you interested in the internal state (current size, bit depth, etc.)? If you are talking about the former, there is little to be seen for an HDC - except for the HBITMAP selected into the device context, there is very little information that is visually representable. @Ken GDI objects (e.g. `HDC`) and USER objects (`HWND`) are very different structures. Neither is related to kernel objects referenced through a `HANDLE`.

Comment: @KenWhite wrote "you can't necessarily tell to what it points".  Unless you call [GetObjectType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and then you can.  The original question seems entirely reasonable to me and such a tool seems possible; there are APIs to inspect GDI objects.  Although, sadly, I don't know of such a tool.

Comment: @arx: I specifically said "generic pointer". Calling GetObjectType only tells you it's a GDI object; it gives you no information about the underlying information (anything to "see") related to that object. "Sure, I can call GetObjectType() on this HDC and find out it's an HDC. Wow! That's useful information!" There are APIs to return information about GDI objects, but none of them give you meaningful information to "see". See again the info about inspecting the types in Windows.h.

Comment: @KenWhite So you call [GetObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you get the bitmap bits and you draw them in the debugger.  Or you get a LOGFONT and you display the font name, size and so on.  Or you get a LOGBRUSH and you display its style and color.  For a DC you can display information about all the objects selected into it.  And so on.

Comment: @arx: So write the VS add in that does it for all known WinAPI handle types and post it as an answer, if it's so simple. Oops - it must not be, because **VS doesn't include it already**. There is no **generic way** to display what's behind any WinAPI handle type (which is what I said in my initial comment yesterday, and which you seem intent on arguing with still), and handles themselves are meaningless *except to the WinAPI functions designed to use them*. What part of that statement is unclear to you? You've said "But you can use the WInAPI to use them!" I said that in **my first comment**.

Comment: @KenWhite I imagine it would be a pain in the arse to implement because you would have to inject a thread into the debuggee (or hijack an existing paused thread) to call the GDI functions in the context where the handles mean something.  But just because something is difficult or not in VS doesn't mean that it isn't useful or that it is impossible or that it hasn't been done already by somebody else.  EDIT: So are you saying that your comment is true but has no bearing on the original question?

Comment: @arx: No, I'm saying my comment is true and is totally relevant to the original question. There is **no current way** to view the opaque data structures behind a generic Windows handle. I'm not sure if you're just trying to argue or if you're just not bothering to read the words written here. It would indeed be "a pain in the arse", because it's simply not possible to do so; the handle has no meaning in any context other than the one in which it's obtained, and even then **only to the WinAPI functions designed to use that handle**. That is 100% relevant to the question asked here.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not being deliberately argumentative.  I don't understand why the debugger can't call the WinAPI function on your behalf, extract useful information about the handle and display it in the debugger.  As the original questioner wants.  This would be useful.  In the unlikely event of this having a noticeable effect on the state of the debuggee you could turn it off.